# Swift SpriteKit Layer/Node doesn't load fast enough

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, resume, pause

I created my first simple IOS game and created to Layers the gameLayer with my game and a pauseLayer with a resume Button/Node. In my gameLayer I have a button to pause the game and in my pauseLayer a Button/Node to resume. I did this like that in my function that gets points from the touchesEnded function:

```
    var ispaused = false

    func touchend(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    if ispaused == false && pausebutton.contains(pos) {
        pauseLayer.isHidden = false
        view?.isPaused = true
        ispaused = true
    }
    if ispaused == true && resumebutton.contains(pos) {
        pauseLayer.isHidden = true
        view?.isPaused = false
        ispaused = false
    }
    }
```

Everything is working besides that I cant see my resume Button. I can click where it should be and the game resumes. But when I delete the line `view?.isPaused = true`the button is displayed as it should be.
This gave me the idea that the pausing view might also pause the process of loading/displaying my resume Button. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: the Button isnt even a image/ texture yet its only a colored node.

Comment: Why do you need both `view?.isPaused` in addition to `self.isPaused` ?

Comment: ispaused is a var (boolean) I made because I need it for other functions. But I don't think this causes my problem. I added the 
initialization to the 1st line of the code.

Comment: I assume that when `ispaused` is changed it calls a function to display/hide the resume button? If so try putting the `ispaused` statments before the `view?.isPaused`. If that doesn't work, I can't determine without more code.

Comment: sadly no its just some variable and doesn't triggers anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to test out your theory of it not loading quick enough.

You can delay code execution with this:

```
let delayDuration:Double = 1.0 /* In seconds */ 

let totalDelayTime = DispatchTime.now() + delayDuration 

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: totalDelayTime, execute: { view?.isPaused = true })
```

It will wait 1 second before evaluating the `view?.isPaused`

Comment: ty for the idea, somehow your method didnt work for me so I used an SKaction.wait as delay. Everything works fine with a delay but however this wouldnt be ideal for an user if he needs to wait 0.1 seconds or some other delay until the game pauses.

Comment: ok even 0.01 seconds work so this will be good enough for me in the moment

Answer (score 0):

Try this also, not sure if it will work.

```
defer { view?.isPaused = true }
```

The defer statement delays execution until the end of the current scope. Which would be the end of the touchEnd function

Comment: still doesn't load :( gonna stay with my 0.01 s delay.  thank you for your help